# print specific characters in an array of strings

Tags: java, arrays

I need to print specific indexes of strings in an array, for example

```
String[] words = {car, bike, truck};
```

print `words[0][0]` and the result would be `c` and print `words[0][1] = a`.

Also i have to read the array from a text file. What i have so far will print the first word of the array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class DemoReadingFiles
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String[] words = readArray("words.txt");

            System.out.println(words[0]);//i can get it to print specific elements

    }

    public static String[] readArray(String file)
    {
        int ctr = 0;
        try
        {
            Scanner s1 = new Scanner(new File(file));
            while (s1.hasNextLine())
            {
                ctr = ctr + 1;
                s1.next();
            }
            String[] words = new String[ctr];

            Scanner s2 = new Scanner(new File(file));
            for (int i = 0; i < ctr; i = i + 1)
            {
                words[i] = s2.next();
            }
            return words;

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check if this is ok:    System.out.println("Specific character print:" + words[0][0].charAt(0));

Comment: That would be `words[0].charAt(0)` then.

Comment: That works, is there any way to reference multiple characters?

Comment: My bad. It was a typo. It should be System.out.println("Specific character print:" + words[0].charAt(0));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String[] words = {"cars", "bike", "truck"};
  System.out.println("Specific character print:" + words[0].charAt(0));
  System.out.println("Multi character selection printed as follows:" + words[0].substring(1, words[0].length() - 1));

}
```

Output:

```
 Specific character print:c

 Multi character selection printed as follows:ar
```